# Could anyone explain how to use Jsonball with JClouds

Tags: jclouds

I am trying to do something like following

BootstrapConfig config = BootstrapConfig.builder().runList(runlist).attributes(new JsonBall("{ \"cassandra\" : { \"cluster_name\" : \"testing Baby\"}}")).build();

but it's not working...

I am not sure how to use Jsonball..

thnx

Answer (score 0):

The code looks good. As Chef attributes have an arbitrary structure, we can't have the corresponding Java one, so we use the JsonBall object as a placeholder for any JSON string.

After generating the bootstrap configuration, however, you need to do the following to generate the bootstrap script:

```
chefService.updateBootstrapConfigForGroup("groupname", config);
Statement bootstrap = chefService.createBootstrapScriptForGroup("groupname");
```

That will generate the bootstrap script you can pass to the ComputeService methods.

- The first call will persist the bootstrap configuration in a data bag, so it can be reused later to bootstrap more nodes with the same configuration.
- The second line will read the contents of that data bag and generate the corresponding bootstrap script.